# The size of the EditText does not fit to the content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have a little problem with the dynamically created EditText where i enter text via a small keyboard That I created, replacing the original Android. The text is insert with the append, but the size of EditText  does not fit the text. Why?

with this solution:

```
EditText et = new EditText(myContext);

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 

et.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I have this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(9544): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(9544): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow$LayoutParams
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.TableRow.mapIndexAndColumns(TableRow.java:162)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.TableRow.getVirtualChildCount(TableRow.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.TableRow.getColumnsWidths(TableRow.java:287)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.TableLayout.findLargestCells(TableLayout.java:500)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:465)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:431)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1163)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(HorizontalScrollView.java:1159)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onMeasure(HorizontalScrollView.java:303)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime(9544):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: yes, I created a small keyboard and disable classic Android

Comment: i want to autosize the EditText by the content, and I have to do this dynamically in java

Comment: When the content changes size, the edit text (if using wrap_content) should also change size.

Comment: no the problem is that the size of the EditText will not match the text I add remaining small, and not showing me some text entered

Comment: I get that, but have you made it `wrap_content`? If you have, then I'm not sure whats wrong.

Comment: wrap_content where I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
```

Add the parameter to `WRAP_CONTENT`. And also set the desired height layout, fill or wrap. The first is width, second is height.

```
 EditText et = new EditText(myContext);

 LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

 et.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Your solution does not work for me, because my EditText created dynamically, are inserted into a system of TableRow, HorizontalScrollView, Scrollview, TableLayout and FrameLyaout. I need something that acts directly on the measures of the EditText

Comment: This is programmatic way of setting such layouts. As opposed to using XML. When you dynamically create your EditText, apply this.

Comment: sorry, but I was wrong to put the wrap_content. Now I insert the wrap_content correctly at  the creation of the EditText but the EditText but not displayed.

Comment: Hey, You have imported the wrong `LayoutParams` There are many possible imports. According to logcat, you should `import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;` Although usually the linearlayout i specified works. If you fixed this and its just edittext not displaying, Check your neighbour views, they could be hogging the space in the table row.